# send testng report(emailable-report.html) file through mail after executing all test cases

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to send an email after executing the test cases with an attachment of testng generated emailable-report.html file ,But I am resulting in error.

please find the stack trace here and do needful

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;nested exception is:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\test-output (Access is denied)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:421)
at hb.util.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:148)
at hb.util.SendMail.execute(SendMail.java:29)
at hb.listeners.CustomListener.onTestFailure(CustomListener.java:41)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:778)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sending the mail in your after suite method...

Comment: Yes I am trying to do that

Comment: Hello Vicky, I resolved the issue ,but it was sending the previous execution  report (emailable-report.html) file instead of current execution report . Can you please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're sending emailable-reports while your test is running you're getting `FileNotFoundException` .Reports get generated only after test execution.

**EDIT** : If you're sending your emailable reports for the test which has already been executed then you will get previous test report as the current test is still running.

I have explained about the solution to this problem in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237318/testng-emailable-report-issue/31266239#31266239)

> I want to send a mail when ever the test case is failed. So I am
>   trying to attach the emailable-report.html file because it's having
>   all the data. so I am trying attach that

You can send the mail with the error which occurred but you cannot attach the report in the mail as the test is still executing

```
//This method will automatically be called if a test fails
            public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {

                //returns the test which failed
                result.getMethod().getMethodName());

                //create an object of the send mail class and call the method which send the mail and pass the test name which failed as an argument to it.

            }
```

If you want to attach reports then you have to set it as a post build option either using `jenkins` or tools like `maven,ant`.Or the other option is to generate your own custom report from the test results which you have got from methods `onTestSuccess`(passed tests),`onTestFailure`(failed tests),`onTestSkipped`(skipped tests)

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you have any doubts

Comment: Hello Vicky Thanks for your reply and answer. I am using the CustomListenter by implementing ITestListener in that onTestFailure() , i was implemented the logic to send an email.Because I want to send an email if test case was failed

Comment: Hi @QAMember I can't understand your question...Do you want to send mail only on Testfailure and you don't want to attach email-able report

Comment: Hello Vicky, I want to send a mail when ever the test case is failed. So I am trying to attach the emailable-report.html file because it's having all the data. so I am trying attach that

Comment: @QAMember you cannot attach the email report on your 'onTestFailure' method as test is still executing and report has not been generated...pls refer my above edit

Comment: Thank you @Vicky,That I have understood by your post.Actually I don't require that html report but I want to show some information about why the test case has been failed .so that I have choose html report.

Comment: @QAMember Happy to be of help...